# Office 365 API Personal Access Token?

Tags: rest, outlook, office365, azure-active-directory

I have an application which must communicate with the Office365 API (resources such as the Calendar API). This application has an account for itself, so I would need a 'Personal Access Token'.

Since the application is not a service for multiple users, I do not need the whole OAuth 2.0 flow, with redirections, perimissions etc. I just need a token that I would send on the HTTP Request and then, on the Office365 UI, all the actions that my application performed would appear as if they were performed by its User.

Is this scenario possible? Github, for instance, offers this alternative: https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens

In the documentation, I read about [OAuth2 Client Credential Flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/), which seems to be a solution for my case. However, it looks more complicated than it should + I do not know on which user's behalf will the application act? Maybe on behalf of the User which registered the application?

Any clarification or hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Client Credentials flow, you will not act on behalf of anyone. You are acting as the app in that case. And that is the simplest flow you know, it is not complicated ;)

The real solution would be to acquire a token using Authorization Code flow, and then store the refresh token so you can always get a new access token via the Refresh Token flow.

This requires the standard redirect, and then when you get the authorization code, exchange it for tokens using client id + client secret + code + resource identifier (O365 API's or Microsoft Graph API's) + redirect URI you used + grant_type = authorization_code.

Refresh token is pretty simple since you call the /oauth2/token endpoint with grant_type=refresh_token + client id + client secret + refresh token + resource identifier. And you get back an access token + new refresh token.

Another solution (which I do not really recommend) is to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. In that one you send client id + client secret + username + password + resource identifier + grant_type=password to the token endpoint.

Reasons not to use the ROPC flow:

1. Does not work if user has MFA/is federated
2. Storing username and password somewhere

Comment: Ok, it seems then that the Client Credentials flow is the recommended way. Then how can I enter the UI and see what the application did, what meetings did it create etc? I was also told now that we have an account with "ApplicationImpersonation" role, which seems to me is exactly what I need for the "Personal Access Token" case, as in the Github example.

Comment: If you need to act on behalf of a user, then I would recommend authorization code + refresh token. But if you don't need to impersonate anyone, then client credentials is indeed best, though it requires that you give the app the necessary access so that it can access the data without a user context.